# Dataframe / For-Loop Help - Trying to change any number greater than 0 to the column number

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataframe with relative abundances for taxon. I am making a Venn diagram and need my data in a presence/absence format. I would like to correspond to column number, where I have data like:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 3 |

Instead of manually changing values manually, I need to find out how I can use R.  I have found a way to change values to column numbers, however it changes the entire row and not just values greater than zero. I tried adding if statements, however it doesn't work the way that I have defined `i`.

```
# I tried this first - which changes all values in the column to column number. 

for(i in 1:ncol(x)) {
  x[ ,i] <- i 
}

# not quite sure how to change it to account for the values and only change value if > 0 

# Doing something like this did not work... I added if statement both before and after defining  
# x[,i] <- i to see what that would do... but no luck. 

for(i in 1:ncol(x)) {
  if(x == 0) {
    return(0)
  }
    x[,i] <- i
}
```

Comment: Not sure I totally follow the expected result, but do you mean like `x[x > 0] <- col(x)[x > 0]` ?

Comment: Yes, this also works! I wasn't sure how to use base R and thought it would be easier to use a for-loop. Both this answer and that below worked perfectly -- thank you!

Comment: Glad it works. There's nothing wrong with a for loop, but often R will allow you to assign a lot of values all at once too using other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close! This should work:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(x)) {
  x[x[, i] > 0 ,i] <- i 
}
```

The above will actually be quite efficient, but you might find this a little more readable:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(x)) {
  x[, i] <- ifelse(x[ ,i] > 0, i, 0)
}
```